# Plot percentage in bar chart with data from different variables

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am quite new to R and I have the following question.

I have  a data.frame like this:

```
mydata.df <- data.frame(ID.name = c("1000", "1000", "1000", "1001","1001",1001,"1002","1002"),
                        project_name = c("project1", "project1", "project1", "project1","project1","project1","project2", "project2"), 
                        Canonical_Hugo_Symbol = c("gene1", "gene3", "gene1", "gene1","gene3","gene4","gene1", "gene2"))
```

and I am trying to plot the different genes on x and the percentage on y accounting for the fact that some gene are just in one project_set and other in the other.

I have tried with:

```
q <- qplot(Canonical_Hugo_Symbol, data= mydata.df, geom="bar", fill= project_name, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))
q + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, hjust = 1)) + stat_bin(geom = "text", aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")), vjust = 5)
```

but as an example gene2  is just present in project2 and should have  a percentage of 100% since is present in all (one) patients.

Thank a lot!

I Just want to edit the data.frame to make it more "real"

```
dput(subset_mydata[c(1:10,1065:1077),c(3,9,20)])
structure(list(ID.name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 
141L, 141L, 142L, 142L, 142L), .Label = c("", "1075", "1104", 
"1108", "1120", "1121", "1137", "1258", "1264", "1280", "1286", 
"1310", "1317", "1338", "1392", "1401", "1435", "1477", "1480", 
"1494", "1519", "1574", "1588", "1595", "1607", "1611", "1644", 
"1645", "1651", "1653", "1654", "1673", "1687", "1702", "1714", 
"1740", "1776", "1781", "1812", "1835", "1838", "1857", "1874", 
"1890", "1899", "1911", "1933", "1936", "1999", "2006", "2046", 
"2063", "2079", "2081", "2088", "2116", "2135", "2144", "2147", 
"2155", "2166", "2167", "2176", "2183", "2200", "2209", "2223", 
"2253", "2256", "2442", "2444", "2453", "2456", "2462", "2467", 
"2472", "2482", "2497", "2504", "2507", "2513", "2518", "2523", 
"2567", "2568", "2576", "2578", "2598", "2600", "2619", "2623", 
"2625", "2632", "2636", "2646", "2652", "2659", "2660", "2676", 
"2680", "2682", "2705", "2711", "2756", "2765", "2772", "2793", 
"2803", "2854", "2856", "2882", "2912", "2916", "2919", "3058", 
"3063", "3114", "3116", "3117", "3125", "3132", "3140", "3145", 
"3175", "3181", "3248", "3383", "3431", "3436", "3442", "3472", 
"3576", "3639", "4093", "FL1_01215", "FL10_01501", "FL12_01593", 
"FL13_01598", "FL16_01738", "FL17_01752", "FL18_01763", "FL19_01881", 
"FL2_01222", "FL22_02025", "FL23_02032", "FL24_02085", "FL25_02175", 
"FL26_02242", "FL28_02459", "FL3_01235", "FL30_02558", "FL35_02726", 
"FL37_02808", "FL41_02865", "FL43_02926", "FL44_02994", "FL45_03018", 
"FL47_03119", "FL48_03128", "FL55_03303", "FL62_03406", "FL64_03418", 
"FL65_03421", "FL69_03484", "FL7_01306", "FL70_03517", "FL71_03534", 
"FL76_03644", "FL77_03651", "FL8_01425"), class = "factor"), 
project_name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("", "FL_Ontogeny", "Hemoseq1"), class = "factor"), 
Canonical_Hugo_Symbol = structure(c(174L, 158L, 113L, 113L, 
97L, 175L, 14L, 9L, 35L, 65L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 111L, 123L, 
113L, 113L, 160L, 50L, 50L, 25L, 25L, 131L), .Label = c("", 
"ABCA7", "ACTA2", "ACTB", "ALMS1", "ARID1A", "ARID1B", "ARID2", 
"ARID3A", "ASXL1", "ATM", "B2M", "BCAS3", "BCL2", "BCL7A", 
"BCL9", "BCORL1", "BCR", "BIRC3", "BLNK", "BRAF", "BRD2", 
"BRWD3", "BTG1", "BTG2", "BTG3", "CA10", "CARD11", "CCDC80", 
"CCND1", "CCND2", "CCND3", "CD40", "CD58", "CD79A", "CD79B", 
"CDH23", "CDK4", "CDK6", "CDKN2A", "CDKN2B", "CELSR2", "CHD1", 
"CHD2", "CHRM3", "CIITA", "CNOT1", "COL4A2", "COL6A2", "CREBBP", 
"CRLF2", "CTSS", "CUL9", "CXCR4", "DDX3X", "DGKG", "DIRAS3", 
"DLEU2", "DMD", "DNAH9", "DNM2", "DNMT3A", "DST", "DTX1", 
"EP300", "EPHA6", "EPHA7", "EPRS", "ETS1", "ETV6", "EZH2", 
"FAM135B", "FAM155A", "FAM18A", "FAS", "FAT2", "FBXO11", 
"FCGR2A", "FCGR3A", "FOXO1", "GNA13", "GNAS", "GNB1", "GNB2", 
"GOPC", "HCK", "HEATR1", "HUWE1", "ID3", "IDH1", "IDH2", 
"IKBKE", "IKZF1", "IKZF2", "IKZF3", "IRF4", "IRF8", "JAK1", 
"KAT2A", "KAT2B", "KAT5", "KDM6A", "KIF20B", "KLHL6", "LRRC16A", 
"MALT1", "MAP3K14", "MAP4K1", "MCL1", "MDM2", "MEF2B", "MLL", 
"MLL2", "MPDZ", "MSH6", "MTAP", "MUC16", "MUM1", "MYC", "MYD88", 
"NBAS", "NF1", "NFKB2", "NOTCH1", "NOTCH2", "NPM1", "NR3C1", 
"OSBP2", "P2RY8", "PASD1", "PAX5", "PCLO", "PDGFC", "PDGFRA", 
"PDGFRB", "PHF6", "PIK3CA", "PIK3CD", "PIK3R1", "PIM1", "POSTN", 
"PRKDC", "PTEN", "RASSF8", "RB1", "RELN", "RET", "RFTN1", 
"RFX7", "RHOA", "RIPK3", "RNF213", "ROS1", "SAMD9", "SBF1", 
"SETD2", "SF3B1", "SGK1", "SIN3A", "SLITRK6", "SMARCA2", 
"SMARCA4", "SMARCB1", "SOCS1", "SOX5", "STAT3", "STAT6", 
"SWAP70", "SYK", "TBL1XR1", "TET2", "TMEM30A", "TNFAIP3", 
"TNFRSF14", "TP53", "TRAF2", "TRAF3", "TRAF6", "TTC27", "TYK2", 
"U2AF1", "UBR5", "UGGT1", "ULK4", "UNC13B", "UNC5C", "UNC5D", 
"USP6", "VPS13A", "XPO1", "ZMAT4", "ZNF608", "ZNF708", "ZRSR2"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID.name", "project_name", 
"Canonical_Hugo_Symbol"), row.names = c(1L, 49L, 94L, 96L, 111L, 
 115L, 125L, 127L, 134L, 138L, 18794L, 18796L, 18797L, 18798L, 
 18800L, 18801L, 18802L, 18803L, 18805L, 18806L, 18809L, 18810L, 
 18814L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm totally confused by your naming. What are patients?

Comment: ID.name are the patients

Comment: Currently the text labels are: 12%, 38%, 12%, 25%, 12%. Please specify what you would like them to be: from your question it's not very clear what the desired output is.

Comment: You should aggregate outside ggplot as the answer shows. However, there are several ways to do so. Using data.table, dplyr, plyr depending of the size of your data and knowdlege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not getting "100%" for gene 2, because your percentage calculation was dividing the observations of each subgroup (project by gene type) by the sum of all the `mydata.df` observations.

If I understood you correctly you want the percentage of each project per type of gene.

```
#added two additional values to gene4.
mydata.df <- data.frame(ID.name = c("1000", "1000", "1000", "1001","1001",1001,"1002","1002","1000","1003"),
                    project_name = c("project1", "project1", "project1", "project1","project1","project1","project2", "project2","project2","project2"), 
                    Canonical_Hugo_Symbol = c("gene1", "gene3", "gene1", "gene1","gene3","gene4","gene1", "gene2","gene4","gene4"))

#use aggregate function to summarize data per ID.name:

#at gene level - and 
table1 = aggregate(mydata.df$ID.name,by=list(Canonical_Hugo_Symbol=mydata.df$Canonical_Hugo_Symbol), length) #number of patients per type of gene
#at gene/project level
table2 = aggregate(mydata.df$ID.name,by=list(Canonical_Hugo_Symbol=mydata.df$Canonical_Hugo_Symbol,project_name=mydata.df$project_name), length) #number of patients per type of gene/project

temp=merge(table1,table2,by=1) #merge table 1 and table 2 - this will be useful to calculate percentages of patients inside each gene and project
names(temp)[c(2,4)] = c("Total_gene","Total_gene_project") #change columns name on the df

percentage = temp$Total_gene_project/temp$Total_gene*100 #calculate percentage
percentage = round(percentage,0)

temp=data.frame(temp,pctg=percentage) #create new df as input to ggplot

pos = ifelse(temp$project_name=="project1",temp$Total_gene_project,temp$Total_gene) #these values will guide the position of labels "percentages"

df = data.frame(temp,pos=pos)

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=Canonical_Hugo_Symbol,y=Total_gene_project,fill=project_name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  xlab("Type of Gene") + ylab("Number of Patients") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, hjust = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=pos,label=paste(pctg, "%")),vjust=2)
```

[image]

**Update** - The code also works with your real data.

[image]

In the code above, assuming the dataframe name is `mydata.df`, just set the object `pos` with the correct name for "project 1" (for example: "FL_Ontogeny").